# Asp.Net MVC 2 - Invalid Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, routes

Once the app is deployed to the web server, I type in an invalid route the mvc app just hangs and then displays a blank page.

On my local IIS, if I type an invalid route I get the exception: "System.Web.HttpException: The incoming request does not match any route.". I want the exception not the blank page.

Any ideas?

Comment: I apologize if this sounds like a redundant question, but is the webserver updated view Windows Update?  I think it might have something to do with specific dlls not being on the machine. (I'm not a web guy, just throwing it out there, thinking the framework might not be up to date.)

Comment: The web server is up to date. One odd thing I am doing is copying the MVC dll locally so that MVC does not need to be installed on the server. In summary on my local machine MVC is installed, on the server the MVC dll is copied to the bin folder of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a missing HttpHandler in the config file. My local config had the hanlder the config on the webserver did not.

```
<add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" 
     type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, 
           Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
           PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```